# Azure Functions - local development: How to respect environment in trigger annotation?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus

In a Function App that we develop locally in Visual Studio, we have two environments
to run against: Test and Development.

Now, we have a `local.settings.json` and two respective environment-specific `local.settings.<environment>.json`
which works totally fine - **with one exception**: The values used in the function trigger annotation.

They seem to be resolved before the actual process is even started and from `local.settings.json`, only.

It's dotnet 6, v4, isolated process.
The project is set up to read from `local.settings.json` *and* `local.settings.<environment>.json`.

The relevant files look like this:

lauchSettings.json

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "My.Project.Functions": {
      ...,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT": "Test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

local.settings.Test.json

```
{
    "myTopicName": "some-topic-for-test",
    "myServiceBusConnection": "Endpoint=sb://MyTestBusURI"
}
```

MyFunction.cs

```
public class MyFunction
{

    [Function(nameof(MyFunctionAsync))]
    public async Task MyFunctionAsync(
       [ServiceBusTrigger("%myTopicName%", Connection = "myServiceBusConnection")] // <-- error here
       MyMessageEntity myMessageEntity)
    {
        // resolving environment-specific values _here_ will work perfectly fine.
        await _someIrrelevantService.DoSomethingAsync(myMessageEntity);
    }
}
```

If we do not have `myTopicName` and `myServiceBusConnection` in `local.settings.json` but only in the environment specific settings, the app won't start, complaining that the respective settings are not found.

We really would like to avoid having to copy around settings, making this tedious and error-prone.

I have been through *a lot* of Microsoft documentation, which unfortunately never speaks about environment specific settings files in local development. So, I am dreading this may not even be possible but:

Does anyone have an idea, how I can make the tooling respect the environment specific settings **in the annotation**?
("You cannot" would be a valid answer, so I can continue looking for workarounds without a bad conscience :) )

---

As requested: We load configs like so:

```
return hostBuilder
           .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
           {
               builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                      .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                      .AddJsonFile($"local.settings.{context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                      .AddEnvironmentVariables();
           })
```

**Which is working fine** but is irrelevant because it happens, ***after*** the annotation's references are resolved.

Comment: Can you post how you're loading your configuration? Keep in mind local.settings.json are loaded by the framework. Also, loading config from a file is not recommended, specially if you're running this on a Consumption plan.

Comment: @lopezbertoni configs from file happens only during development (and testing), running it _locally_ on developers' machines.